# Draw 4.000 Points or Lines in iOS objective-c from inside UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, cgpoint

I have an NSArray with over 4.000 CGPoints

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(213, 30)], ...
```

and want to draw the points or lines between them from inside my UIViewController. What is the best way for iOS devices?
thnx

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Will the points change or is it a one-time-draw?

Comment: first I want to start to draw one-time. later I want a fingers touch to attract the points by force, changing their position (and redraw).

Comment: Do you intend to redraw it as the user moves the finger or after the finger has lifted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to work with sprites or particle generation? Without knowing more details, I can only give a generic answer, but lemme give it a shot. Let's assume the points are all simple 1-pixel coloured thingies. No gradients or paths required, just "set the pixel at x,y to red/green/blue."

You should easily be able to manipulate 4,000 `CALayer` objects simultaneously:

```
CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer]; // assumes self is a view controller
NSMutableArray *mSprites = [NSMutableArray array]; // to store references to the layers

for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    NSAssert1(layer != nil, @"failed to create CALayer #%i", i);

    layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:... green:... blue:... alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(rand(), rand(), 1.0, 1.0);

    [mSprites addObject:layer];
    [rootLayer addSublayer:layer];
}

self.my4000SpritesProperty = mSprites;
```

Then, when it's time to manipulate them, go into the array at `self.my4000SpritesProperty` and change the layers' frames or other properties.

For 4,000 elements, you should see acceptable performance with Core Animation.

Comment: offtopic: why not drawing the 4000 Points in the drawRect method ?

Comment: because the view is dynamic and there is no extra class for it.

Comment: Because drawing 4,000 elements with Quartz/Core Graphics would likely be too slow to be usable.

Comment: Don't forget to test on a device. The simulator runs much faster.